# Permalink and Title using echo

Tags: php, wordpress, title, permalinks

First, I'm sorry for my bad english.

Ok, I'm using this code in single.php on my worpdress, it will make post horizontally

```html
<?php
// Show a selected number of posts per row
$posts_per_row = 5;
$posts_per_page = 20;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
   'paged' => $paged,
);
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) {
   while (have_posts()) {
      the_post();
      if ((++$post_counter % $posts_per_row) == 1  || $posts_per_row == 1) {
         if ($post_counter > 1) {
            echo "</div><!-- End of post_row -->\n";  // End previous row
         }
         echo "<div class='post_row'>\n";  // Start a new row
      }
      echo "<div class='post_class'>\n";  // Start one post
      // Output post data here
      echo '<h2>';the_title();echo '</h2>';
      the_excerpt();
      echo "</div><!-- End of post_class -->\n";  // End of post
   } ?>
   </div><!-- End of post_row -->
   <div class='clear'></div>
   <div class="navigation">
    <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Older Entries') ?></div>
    <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries »') ?></div>
   </div>
<?php } else {
   // Code for no posts found
}
?>
```

But, the result is just Title and post summary, how I can make post title with permalink as the link,  like this code

```html
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

I think, I should edit

```html
echo '<h2>';the_title();echo '</h2>';
```

So, can anyone tell me the correct code ?

Answer (score 2):

**Very Simple**

```
    echo '<h2>'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</h2>'; // For title
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

`<h2><a href="<?php echo  the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></h2>`

you should use `<?php echo the_title(); ?>` or `<?=  the_title(); ?>`